# Updating MYSQL with average score

Tags: mysql

I have two tables fluids and cas and I'm trying to update a related table fluids with the average score from the cad table. Something like this:

```
UPDATE fluids INNER JOIN cas on cas.cas = fluids.cas 
SET fluids.score = avg(cas.score) GROUP BY cas.cas
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to store data that can be easily calculated 'on-the-fly'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your aggregate select as a subquery:

```
UPDATE fluids 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cas,avg(cas.score) as avg_score
    FROM cas
    GROUP BY cas 
) as c ON c.cas = fluids.cas 
SET fluids.score = c.avg_score
```